# Can I Drop and Create an empty Athena table over S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I want to create an **empty** Athena table over an S3 bucket which *will hold rows from other Athena tables*. After each day, the data in this table gets old for my use case and hence I have to drop it and create a new table and insert latest rows into it.This table will be filled with rows from other tables and has nothing to do with data in the S3 bucket it is being created in. I want to use this table to just insert rows into it from other Athena tables, so that I can use quicksight on the data.

Right now, when I Drop and Create the Athena table over the same S3 bucket, it shows all the previous rows that were inserted into it. So in essence, how do I delete these previously inserted rows and get a empty table each time? 
Right now I do something like this:

`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS athena-table`

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS athena-table LOCATION 'SAME_S3_BUCKET'`

Comment: Athena doesn't store any data, when queries are run , it goes to source datastore and fetches the results, whether its S3 or any other JDBC sources behind it. I am not sure what `it shows all previous rows` meant, are you saying that even though s3 data is deleted, Athena still fetches the records?

Comment: If you want the table data to be gone you need to delete the table data. And the table data is the one in the S3 bucket. Remove the objects in the bucket and athena should no longer see the old data. alternatively, start using prefixes in your bucket and for each day create a new prefix and update athena to point to a different prefix each day.

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks this is helpful. Deleting the table data is the best solution for me. INSERT INTO query adds data into S3 bucket, I wanted to find out if there is a way I can delete the inserted rows directly using Athena without having to do it through S3. I am using boto3, if that helps.